# Erro ao tentar criar em ambiente Windows um controller em RubyOnRails usando no Gemfile gem tiny_tds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4

Configurei no SO Windows um ambiente RubyOnRails e preciso acessa um banco **MSSQL** com uma base já criada e populada, queria apenas consultar o banco e retornar dados através das Query. Vi que existe uma Gem chamada **tiny_tds**, configurei certinho no arquivo Gemfile, porém quando tento criar um controller ou rodar o server retorna um erro. Descrevo abaixo:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file --
tiny_tds/tiny_tds (LoadError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:26:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
        from C:/Users/daciolima/Documents/DESENVOLVIMENTO/Ruby/gerencial/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que seja?
Já configurei o mesmo projeto em ambiente Linux e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa do tinytds disponível no S.O.

Como você instalou o ruby?

Se usar esta distribuição vem tudo pronto para usar:

http://www.railsinstaller.org/pt-BR